# How to set up object position with keyboard press?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

hy
I want to make game, where are different places where I want to start my mini golf game...
So when I expl. press 1 ,then take my ball to the specific positon for expl. to x 5,y 10 ,z 15

How can I make int C#  in Unity3d?

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: this is not the type of question you ask in stackoverflow

Comment: You should first try to write code for this. If you get stuck while coding, you can ask question here to get help related to that specific problem.

Comment: I recommend you watch a tutorial first and try it yourself, then try asking questions here if it didn't work.

Comment: This question is quite unclear. Please rephrase a little bit. Also, maybe give us some code to work with. 

Also, I think you could find an online tutorial pretty easily. There are many out there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I have made, it is commented to explain to you along the way:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class testscript : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    List<KeyCode> keys; //array also acceptable here, but i prefer to use Lists
    //for line above, this could also be a List<string> because of the other overload of Input.GetKey but this way is best practice

    [SerializeField]
    Transform transform;

    [SerializeField]
    List<Vector3> pos;

    void Update(){
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++) { //not foreach because we will need value of i
            if (Input.GetKey (keys [i])) { //this will be continuous, you could also use input.GetKeyDown
                //*****************
                //DO SOMETHING HERE
                //*****************
                transform.position = pos[i];
                Debug.Log ("Yay! A key was pressed!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And to answer your second question, to make an `int` in C# you do `int varname;` or to define it on creation, you can do `int varname = numval`.